# How to interpret "reduced by" in a math problem

Tags: phrase-usage

If a question says the amount is reduced by 1/4, what does it mean?

For instance, say it's 8

Does it mean:

8 * 1/4 = 2. So, the new amount is 2.

OR

It's 8 - 2 = 6. So, the new amount is 6.

Comment: Yes it does. A quarter is 25% so to reduce something by a quarter is to reduce it by 25%, that means that you're left with 75% or three quarters.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment "Reduce it by 25%", it's exactly the same. You can also say "Reduce it by one fourth" and mean the same thing but that is a very unusual thing to say. You should note, though, that if you _reduce_ something by a quarter and then want to take if back to its original value you have to _increase_ it by  a third as you are starting from the reduced point. Similarly if you reduce something by a quarter and then want to reduce it to a half of its _original_ value you have to reduce it by a third. This is because you have to start from where you are each time.

Comment: @BoldBen I got it. Then, how to word it if he meant to only make it 25% of the original value. So, for 8 the answer is 2, how would you word the question?

Comment: If you reduce 8 *to* one-fourth, the answer is 2.

Comment: Can someone please make the answer official.

Comment: Can you provide more context? What is the actual wording in the problem?

Comment: It could also mean 8.00 - 0.25 = 7.75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the amount 8 has been reduced **by** .25 of itself, it means the new amount is 6.

If the amount 8 has been reduced **to** .25 of itself, it means the new amount is 2.

Comment: I agree that this is most likely the intention of the OP's source.  Be careful though, because "of itself" wasn't in the OP's question.  The correct interpretation could be 8.00 - 0.25 = 7.75.